# AppCenter - authentication failed?

Tags: updates, appcenter

This error I received after opened AppCenter. 
What could this be and how to fix? Or at least, how can I get additional details about the reason?

5.1 Hera

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue today; I opened up Terminal and entered `sudo apt update` and then `sudo apt upgrade`. After that, I rebooted and the issue is gone.